# Clarity Design System Datagrid - iterate through both clrDgItems and ngFor

Tags: html, angular5, vmware-clarity

I'm trying to filter my rows in a datagrid by Clarity Design System. In the [documentation](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v1.0/datagrid/binding-properties), iterating list of model properties can be achieved as follows,

```
<clr-datagrid>
    <clr-dg-column>User ID</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'name'">Name</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'creation'">Creation date</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'pokemon.name'">Pokemon</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'color'">Favorite color</clr-dg-column>

    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let user of users">
        <clr-dg-cell>{{user.id}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{user.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{user.creation | date}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{user.pokemon.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>
            <span class="color-square" [style.backgroundColor]="user.color"></span>
        </clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>

</clr-datagrid>
```

My problem is this, in my application I have a child container inside the `clr-dg-row`. As you can see, here the `abc` is very complex object unlike `users` in the documentation.

```
<clr-datagrid>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'customerReference'">Customer Ref.</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'customerAddress'">Address</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'customerName'">Customer Name</clr-dg-column>

    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let def of abc;">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let xyz of def.groupResult">
              <clr-dg-cell>{{ xyz.customerReference }}</clr-dg-cell>
              <clr-dg-cell>{{ xyz.customerAddress }}</clr-dg-cell>
              <clr-dg-cell>{{ xyz.customerName }}</clr-dg-cell>
        </ng-container>
    </clr-dg-row>
</clr-datagrid>
```

When I say,

1. `<clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'customerReference'">Customer Ref.</clr-dg-column>`

It did not work, then I tried,

2. `<clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'xyz.customerReference'">Customer Ref.</clr-dg-column>`
3. `<clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'def.groupResult.xyz.customerReference'">Customer Ref.</clr-dg-column>`

Not sure if it is even possible, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with your data structure and the code you are using in your app? https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v1-0-fdo2by

Comment: This structure doesn't make sense, you are iterating twice for a single row. If you have a deeply nested data structure, you might want to consider changing it for easier iteration in your template.

Comment: @JeremyWilken So I can't use it for this kind of deeply nested data models is it? Changing the structure is the only solution?

Comment: Provide a demo of your issue and we can better understand what is happening. You can use deep models but iterating just to access nested properties is not a good plan usually.